# Moving mouse in iTerm causes characters to be to printed to prompt

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, iterm2

I am having an issue with iTerm that happens to me intermittently. When I am using iTerm and I move the mouse up and down, or click a bunch of random characters are printed to the prompt:

[image: These are the characters that are printed]

I am in a ssh session on a remote linux machine when this is happening, but when I log out and am working on my own machine everything is fine.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Is “Mouse Reporting” enabled (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa2GF.png)? What is the value of `$TERM` in your remote shell?

Answer (score 0):

I have this happen occasionally. I forget what the cause is, but you can fix it by typing this at the prompt in the window where it is happening:

`$  printf '\e[?2004l' ; printf '\e[?2004h'`

Frankly, I can't remember if two printf's are actually needed there, but can't test it since I don't know what causes it! ;-)